# maven surefire plugin to find native dll

Tags: java, maven, enterprise-architect, maven-surefire-plugin

My problem is to *Maven test* just one of my projects with the **32-bit** java engine in order to be able to use a certain native library (actually **SSJavaCOM.dll** from Sparx Systems). It is not available in 64-bit. All other project should remain to run in in 64-bit jvm.

I am using **Eclipse** with **m2e** and configured a pom.xml for my project. I learned that I can switch jvm in Maven test by using **maven-surefire-plugin** and configuring the **jvm**. I placed the **SSJavaCOM.dll** in **C:\Windows\System32** and thought it should be found.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <jvm>../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_172/bin/java</jvm>
      <forkMode>once</forkMode>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

(I tried C:/ instead of the five ../ without success)

When Run *Maven Test* I get the failure message

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no SSJavaCOM in java.library.path
at eu.ngong.renOld.RenOldTest.commandline_test(RenOldTest.java:40)
```

I also tried to configure Surefire with

```
      <argLine>-Djava.library.path=../../../../../Windows/System32</argLine>
```

but led to the same failure message (also with C:/)

I would appreciate if you got a better idea than configuring Surefire starting the desktop program in 32-bit or help me configure Surefire correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

put the dll in C:\Windows\ **SysWOW64** instead of C:\Windows\ **System32**, as on 64-bit Windows systems System32 shall hold 64-bit dll libraries and SysWOW64 shall hold 32-bit dll libraries.

Windows architects are burdened by naming decisions of their past and by a limited refactoring ability of Windows.

see https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/

Comment: Weird WIndoze. System32 is for 64 bit arch and SysWOW64 for 32??